# how to get specific string form dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

[its a print of the first lines of my dataframe, it have around 11k lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsTBB.png)
its made of twitter data

I was using:
`df.loc[(df["screen_name"]=="vagnerfsm")]`
to get specific lines that have tweets made by this user

but I still don't know how to get lines from a specific day:
`df.loc[(df["created_at"]=="Mon May 25")]`            <- I believe i need some specific code, like * in excel, to make it understand that I want all data that begin with "Mon May 25".
Whats should I put?

Yeah, its a noob question, but I'm learning python since a few weeks, so.. if someone can help...
suggestions are welcome

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the column "created_at" to datetime using

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'],format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
```

to cast to datetime. The format is in https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

When you want to get lines from specific day, 25 May 2020, you can filter the day using

```
df[df['created_at'].dt.date==pd.Timestamp(2020,5,25)]
```